Domination by product measure
I have come across something in Grimmets percolation book, that i don't really know to prove. He states around (7.64), that if $Y_i, i \in S$  are $\{0,1\}$ valued variables for a countable set $S$ together with an ordering $s_1, s_2 \dots, $ and $${P}(Y_{s_{j+1}} = 1|Y_{s_i} = y_i \text{ for } 1 \leq i \leq j) \geq \pi$$ for all $j$ and vectors $y_1,\dots,y_j$ for which
$${P}(Y_{s_i} = y_i \text{ for } 1 \leq i \leq j) >0.$$
Then $\text{Law(Y)}$ would stochastically dominate the product measure $\mu_\pi$ with density $\pi$ on $\{0,1\}^S$.
Stochastic domination means, that for every increasing (using the parial order of $\{0,1\}^S$) function $f$ $$\int f d \text{Law(Y)} \geq \int f d\mu_\pi.$$
I thought about using the condition to disect $$P(\bigcap_{i = 1}^n\{Y_i = y_i\}) = P(Y_n = y_n | \bigcap_{i = 1}^{n-1}Y_i = y_i)$$ and iterate this to get $$P(\bigcap_{i = 1}^n\{Y_i = y_i\}) \geq \pi^n$$
but this only works for $y_i = 1$.
Furthermore I'm not sure if and how to extend this to infinite intersections (can i simply do this without any assumption) and how to show the actual domination property with the integral. Thanks.

I am speculating, but it smells of Holley's theorem: note that indeed if $Z\sim\mu_\pi$, then $\pi=\mu_\pi(Z_{s_{j+1}}=1)=\mu_{\pi}(Z_{s_{j+1}}=1|Z_{s_i}=y_i~\text{for}~1\leq i\leq j)$. The result is stated for finite $S$ but I suspect there's a nice workaround. Check section 4.2 here: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9905031

Thanks! Seems like it could work, if we get it to extend. I'm just wondering if there is a more "basic" way of proving this

Coupling is a powerful method. For the sake of simplicity, let's assume $S = \mathbb{N}$ without losing the generality. We'll prepare the setting as follows:

$(U_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a family of IID RVs, each uniformly distributed on $[0, 1]$.

$p(y_{[1:n]}) = \mathbb{P}(Y_{n+1} = 1 \mid Y_{[1:n]} = y_{[1:n]})$ for each $y_{[1:n]} = (y_1, \ldots, y_n) \in \{0, 1\}^{n}$.

We define $(\tilde{Y}_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $(\tilde{Z}_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ as follows:
$$ \tilde{Y}_n = \mathbf{1}[p(\tilde{Y}_{[1:n-1]}) \geq U_n]
\qquad \text{and}\qquad
\tilde{Z}_n = \mathbf{1}[\pi \geq U_n]. $$
Here, we regard $\tilde{Y}_{[1:0]} = \varnothing$ and $p(\varnothing) = \mathbb{P}(Y_1 = 1)$, ensuring that $\tilde{Y}$ is well-defined inductively.


Now let's prove the following claim:

Claim. $\mathrm{Law}(\tilde{Y}) = \mathrm{Law}(Y)$ and $\mathrm{Law}(\tilde{Z}) = \mu_{\pi}$. Also, $\tilde{Y} \geq \tilde{Z}$.

Indeed, the assumption implies that $p(y_{[1:n]}) \geq \pi$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Then by the construction, we can prove by induction that, for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$ \tilde{Y}_n \geq \tilde{Z}_n $$
and
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{Law}(\tilde{Y}_n \mid \tilde{Y}_{[1:n-1]} = y_{[1:n-1]})
&= \mathrm{Ber}(p(y_{[1:n-1]})) \\
&= \mathrm{Law}(Y_n \mid Y_{[1:n-1]} = y_{[1:n-1]})
\end{align*}
for any $y_{[1:n-1]} \in \{0, 1\}^{n-1}$.
The former implies that $Y \geq Z$ in the lattice $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$. Moreover, since the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\{0,1\})^{\otimes\mathbb{N}}$ is generated by the cylindrical events, the latter proves that $\mathrm{Law}(\tilde{Y}) = \mathrm{Law}(Y)$. Finally, it's clear that $\mathrm{Law}(\tilde{Z}) = \mathrm{Ber}(\pi)^{\otimes\mathbb{N}} = \mu_\pi $. Thus, the claim follows.
Now by the claim, for any increasing $f : \{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N} \to [0, +\infty]$,
\begin{align*}
\int f(\omega) \, \mathbb{P}(Y \in \mathrm{d}\omega)
&= \int f(\omega) \, \mathbb{P}(\tilde{Y} \in \mathrm{d}\omega) \\
&= \mathbb{E}[ f(\tilde{Y}) ]
\geq \mathbb{E}[ f(\tilde{Z}) ] \\
&= \int f(\omega) \, \mathbb{P}(\tilde{Z} \in \mathrm{d}\omega)
= \int f(\omega) \, \mu_{\pi}(\mathrm{d}\omega),
\end{align*}
Therefore, the desired conclusion follows.
